# automatically download package when pod restarts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am again and again downloading and install a package whenever a pod restarts so how can I automate it.
I wanted the pod to automatically install or download a package when the pod restarts.how can I do it in Kubernetes?

Comment: You can install that's required packages in the image. can you elaborate the situation ?

Comment: You need to provide more information if your unsatisfied with the answers you're receiving, and ultimately it sounds like you're after anti-patterns. You're getting the best (i.e. best-practice) responses given this fairly basic, straight-forward question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 (best practice):**

If you want the package to be downloaded and installed in the container inside of the Pod when it starts, then you must add those download and install instructions to the `Dockerfile` using the `RUN` directive.

If you’re using a public image, and not your own custom image, then you’ll want to create a `Dockerfile` and use the public image as the base image to create and push your own custom Docker image to a image repository. You do this by adding the `FROM` directive as the first line of the Dockerfile.

There are a ton of tutorials out there on how to build images with Dockerfiles and push them to a repository for use by Kubernetes. Here’s the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder) from Docker which explains the aforementioned directives and everything else you need to know to create Dockerfiles, build them into Docker images, and push them to a image repository like Docker Hub.

In short, you’ll end up with a Dockerfile that looks something like this, which adds the instructions to download and install the package to a base image:

```
FROM <base image (i.e. the image you’re currently using)>

RUN <download command>
RUN <install command>
```

The linked documentation tells you how to build and push a Docker image to a repo, and then it’s just a matter of updating the `image` field in your Pod manifest.

Now whenever your Pod restarts it will already have the package installed.

**Option 2 (anti-pattern, not recommended):**

*Caution: I'm including this option because OP does not want to use Option 1, so I'm including one possible, theoretical alternative.*

You *could* use an init container to accomplish this. The init container would need to download and install a package for your app container and put it in a mounted [`emptyDir` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes) shared by the init container and app container. This work would be done using the `command` property in the init container.

After your init container runs, your app container can access the package via the mounted shared `emptyDir` volume.

[More about sharing data between containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/).

There are several reasons I could think of off the top of my head for why this is an anti-pattern:

1. It slows down Pod startup time.
2. Your `emptyDir` volume is mutable and if you somehow delete or corrupt the package, and your app container (not Pod) crashes, your Pod will crash loop as your init container only runs on Pod restarts, not container restarts.
3. It unnecessarily complicates your Pod manifest.

Comment: I don't want it to go inside a specific container...just inside the pod

Comment: I read about the concept of init containers...will that help in some case?

Comment: The correct way is to use this concept. Init containers are for different things. Moreover, in your case it will be the same as without it, after restarting a Pod everything will be installed again.

Comment: @unmesh_swar Are there some constraints we don't know about preventing you from rolling your own Docker image? Might help to include _why_ you don't want to go down that route.

Comment: @unmesh_swar I have updated my answer with a second option using init containers. Take a look and LMK what you think.

Answer (score 1):

A pod should be complete - it shouldn't need to download and install a package. You are essentially trying to do a 'build step' during pod startup, this is almost certainly an anti-pattern.

If the image you are using doesn't contain a package then you should build your own image and deploy it to a docker registry or look for a different docker image that contains your required package.

ericstaples has done a good job of explaining how to roll your own docker image and push it do a docker repository.

If you edit your question and provide the image repo:tag that you are currently using and also the package you want to install then you may receive better responses.